# QFields date gone but still here

Tags: qgis, data, qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I used QField on my iPhone for my work and synchronize my data on QFieldCloud but after when I opened my maps in QGIS and my phone The data is gone, but the problem is that I can still see my data on "files" in my phone (/var/mobile/container/data) and the "changes" I did in QFieldCloud but when I download my data it's empty.

What should I do?